# Call to undefined function imagecreatefromwebp() on PHP Version 7.2.2

Tags: centos, cpanel, webp

I am getting this error on PHP Version 7.2.2, which is supposed to come with webp.

does webp need to be installed separately ?

Call to undefined function imagecreatefromwebp()

i run CENTOS 6.9 standard [host] with cpanle  v70.0.12
GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i update os to centos 7.5 and imagecreatefromwebp() work fine